# How to prevent multi selection on SmartFilterBar?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following SmartFilterBar:
[image]

As you can see on the input field, multi selection is possible. How can I prevent multi selection on the field?

I tried:

```
<smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" filterType="smartFilterBar:FilterType.single" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
<smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassNum" filterType="smartFilterBar:FilterType.single" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an annotation which controls this. 
See this.

```
   <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.FilterExpressionRestrictions" >
  <Collection>
     <Record>
        <PropertyValue Property="Property" PropertyPath="Customer" />
        <PropertyValue Property="AllowedExpressions" EnumMember="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.FilterExpressionType/SingleValue" />
     </Record>
     <Record>
        <PropertyValue Property="Property" PropertyPath="CompanyCode" />
        <PropertyValue Property="AllowedExpressions" EnumMember="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.FilterExpressionType/SingleValue" />
     </Record>
  </Collection>
```

Refer https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar/annotations/Summary and search for 'FilterExpressionType' for more detail.